# junit Invoke method on parameter change

Tags: java, junit

Using Java I'm writing parametrized test in junit4 with Parameterized.class runner. For each parameter same set of tests are executed. What I want is to call a method, when parameter is changed.

Business idea is that each of this parameter defines some kind of connection that takes time to establish. I want to establish that connection only once when parameter with connection changes and share it for all test cases.
@beforeClass executed only once, and class constructor/@before executed before each testcase. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `@Before` and each time do a check whether you need to set up a new connection, otherwise do nothing and let the test use the existing one.

Comment: @Luciano van der Veekens the check is not that trivial. I have to introduce static class fields for all previous parameters and check for if any of them been changed. Moreover I have to check if this the first time test starts. That code will not be reusable at all

Comment: Can't you use another parameter for that?